# How to check if a table already exists in the database by using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, exists

Now I am using something like:

```
dbResult = dbStatement.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '[e2]' AND table_name = '[emp101_messages]'");
while(dbResult.next())
{
    int value = -1;
    value= dbResult.getInt(1);
    System.out.println(value + " table count");
}
```

Is this correct way to check if a table exists in a database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'dbname'
  AND table_name = 'my_tablename';

+----------------------+
| table_name           |
+----------------------+
| my_tablename |
+----------------------+
```

As most of the options are already provided. Please see if this can help.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
SHOW [FULL] TABLES [{FROM | IN} db_name]
    [LIKE 'pattern' | WHERE expr]
```

As sometimes you don't have access to metadata.

Answer (score 1):

If you want just check if 1, 2 or a few more tables exists why not use: `mysql> show tables like "test1";`?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE "emp101_messages";
```

I think it's more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

It is a correct way to do so. (Just puzzled by the "[]" braces around your table names -- these are most probably not part of the actual names, so need to be removed)

Moreover, it is an efficient way: since you are providing a constant for both `table_schema` as well as for `table_name`, you are therefore utilizing [INFORMATION_SCHEMA optimizations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-schema-optimization.html), in that the table is not even opened:

```
explain select count(*) from information_schema.tables where table_schema='world' and table_name='City';
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+-------------------------+---------+------+------+---------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type | possible_keys | key                     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                             |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+-------------------------+---------+------+------+---------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tables | ALL  | NULL          | TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME | NULL    | NULL | NULL | Using where; Skip_open_table; Scanned 0 databases |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+-------------------------+---------+------+------+---------------------------------------------------+
```

The "SHOW TABLES" solution offered is good, too -- and practically the same as far as Java/Python/Whatever code goes. The result is a valid ResultSet:

```
SHOW TABLES FROM world LIKE 'City';
+------------------------+
| Tables_in_world (City) |
+------------------------+
| City                   |
+------------------------+
```

But to just complete the story: it is not a standard SQL syntax - so if you're using some framework like an ORM of some sorts, you may not always be able to get by with this type of query (as I recall EJB3 will not let you do so).

Also, it is very difficult to parse on server side, see: [Reading results of SHOW statements, on server side](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/reading-results-of-show-statements-on-server-side), though this may not be a concern to you.